# I can't find the error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appointments')

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo

[image]I'm doing my final project for my coding bootcamp and I'm almost done but I can't move further without solving this. Here is the file the error is coming from.

```jsx
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { GET_APPOINTMENTS, CREATE_APPOINTMENT } from "../utils/mutations";
import { useMutation, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";
import Calendar from "react-calendar";

function AppointmentCalendar() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_APPOINTMENTS);
  const [createAppointment] = useMutation(CREATE_APPOINTMENT);

  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = useState(null);
  const [appointmentText, setAppointmentText] = useState("");

  const handleDateChange = (date) => {
    setSelectedDate(date);
  };

  const handleAddAppointment = () => {
    if (selectedDate && appointmentText.trim() !== "") {
      createAppointment({
        variables: { date: selectedDate.toISOString(), text: appointmentText },
      })
        .then(() => {
          setSelectedDate(null);
          setAppointmentText("");
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error(error);
        });
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Appointment Calendar</h1>
      <div>
        <Calendar onChange={handleDateChange} value={date} />
      </div>
      <div>
        {selectedDate && (
          <div>
            <h2>Appointments for {selectedDate.toLocaleDateString()}</h2>
            <input
              type="text"
              placeholder="Add appointment"
              value={appointmentText}
              onChange={(e) => setAppointmentText(e.target.value)}
            />
            <button onClick={handleAddAppointment}>Add Appointment</button>
            {data.appointments && data.appointments.length > 0 && (
              <ul>
                {data.appointments.map((appointment) => (
                  <li key={appointment.id}>{appointment.text}</li>
                ))}
              </ul>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AppointmentCalendar;
```

I've looked through documentation but I can't seem to find anything.  I'm trying to make it so when I click a date on the calendar it will bring up options.

Comment: You should check `data` has value before checking `data.apointments` exists: `data && data.appointments && data.appointments.length > 0`, or simply `data?.appointments?.length > 0`

Comment: The error states `appointments is undefined`, but I don’t see `appointments` in the code

Comment: @antokhio that's not what the error says at all

Comment: @HaoWu that worked thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`data` will be undefined until `loading` is `false`. It will also not be set if `error` is *truthy*.

You need to check both of those states before trying to use `data`

```jsx
if (loading) {
  return <p>Loading...</p>;
}

if (error) {
  return <p className="error">{error.message}</p>;
}

return (
  <div>
    {/* now you can safely use data... */}
  </div>
);
```

See the Apollo docs for [executing a query](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query), as well as...

- [Inspecting loading states](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-loading-states)
- [Inspecting error states](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#inspecting-error-states)